# how to write a udev rule to remove a tag?

Tags: udev

Is it possible to write a new udev rule that undoes `TAG+="uaccess"` (removes the `uaccess` tag) without undoing any of the other tags on a device?  If so, how?

(I have a device that should be opened by a daemon.  Unfortunately, the `uaccess` tag added in `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules` causes the permissions to be mangled whenever someone logs in, breaking access for the daemon.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [version 217 onwards](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/NEWS?id=v217#n70), is possible to do that using:

```
TAG-="uaccess"
```

For older versions, sadly it isn't. So you can workaround adding some conditional that would prevent the tag from being added:

```
KERNEL=="sdb", GROUP="daemon", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
```

In this case, *you* set the permissions and then nothing else can be added.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of `last_rule`.  This works only if my rule is evaluated before the `TAG+="uaccess"` rule.  I think I can guarantee this ordering if my rules filename is lexically sorted before `70-uaccess.rules`, right?  (e.g., name it `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-uaccess-preempt.rules`)

Comment: @RichardHansen yes

Comment: udev supports removing tags via `TAG-="foo"` as of v217, which was released 2014-10-27.  ([commit](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=8e3ba3772cadf6a8292b0da533062dd4d377af67), [changelog entry](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/NEWS?id=v217#n70))

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer and it didn't work for RHEL7.  The `OPTIONS+="last_rule"` is deprecated.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="1",TAG:="systemd"
```

This needs to run after the `70-uaccess.rules`. Name it `/etc/udev/rules.d/71-uaccess-remove.rules`